# Simple HTTP Proxy on Samsung TV

Tags: http, proxy, samsung-smart-tv

I'm writing an HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) player on Samsung TV. I need to implement an HTTP Proxy which receives every HTTP request sent by Samsung TV Player, modifies the request (by adding a proprietary HTTP header) & sends the modified request to the Media server. Is there a way to implement this type of simple HTTP Proxy on Samsung TV ?

Thanks
S R

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to set up proxy in Samsung TV.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a webapp? Or a dotnet app?
One idea is to override the XMLHttpRequest, so you will be able to add your header to all the requests.
Or maybe the setStreamingProperty from avplay [doc](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/api-references/samsung-product-api-references/avplay-api)